# How to document a nullable union type with jsDoc?

Tags: jsdoc3

According to [jsDoc - tag @type](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html) the correct way to annotate a union type is `@type {(number|boolean)}` and the correct way to annotate a nullable type is `@type {?number}`.

How do I document a type which is a union and nullable at the same time? I tried

- `@type {?(number|boolean)}` -- question mark in front of parentheses
- `@type {(?number|?boolean)}` -- mark every type of the union individually nullable
- `@type {(?number|boolean)}` -- mark only the first type of the union nullable

However, my IDE (JetBrains PhpStorm) compains about every variant.